# DRY in filtering?

Tags: javascript

```js
list = list.filter(({ field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7}) => {
        let found = false;

        if (field1.includes(this.state.filterString) ||
        field2.includes(this.state.filterString) ||
        field3.includes(this.state.filterString) ||
        field4.includes(this.state.filterString) ||
        field5.includes(this.state.filterString) ||
        field6.includes(this.state.filterString) ||
        field7.includes(this.state.filterString) ||
        ) {
          found = true;
        }
        return found
      });
```

The above code looks very repetitive and I'm wondering if it's possible to make it more concise or by not violating DRY principle?

Comment: please explain what is the desired result and what is the precise problem, otherwise, the question is too broad and can be answered with a simple Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array of properties followed by a `.some` test:

```
const itemProperties = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5', 'field6', 'field7'];
const { filterString } = this.state;
const filteredList = list.filter(
  item => itemProperties.some(prop => item[prop].includes(filterString))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on an object for which you want to check the filter string on *every* key, you can also do it using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```
list.filter(item => Object.values(item).some(prop => prop.includes(filterString)))
```

Comment: Yeap but because for my case there is only certain number of fields needed to be checked instead